# Insert Audio in APK file

Tags: android, audio, apk

Sorry, I'm newbie in Apk editing. I need to add audio into an apk-file. I'm using Apk Editor or Android Studio firstly. I am placing my audio (music.mp3) into the res/raw/ directory. But now I need some code that starts the music. What should that code be and where to be placed, into which XML-file?. 
Thank you!

Comment: Depending on the app and the method you used to decompile the app, you would have got either `.smali` files or `.java` files. To start the music, you could probably add a button with an `onClickListener` that starts the music. However most of the new code tends to garble the output and the recompilation fails. You could use some hacky techniques to work your way around.

Comment: I could try adding this code below:
MediaPlayer ring= MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.ring);
ring.start();       
but into which XML-file?... I have a public.xml file under /res/values/. Should it probably be there?.

Comment: Your code must be added in `java` files. XML files don't give functions(mostly).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open the android studio with the project in which you want to add-on audio clip/media file.

Step 2: Create a raw folder.

Step 3: Add media file to raw folder by simply copy and paste that to raw folder.adding-media-in-android-studio

Step 4: Here we added a media file “ring.mp3” . Now open the Java File of desired activity, here we are adding audio in MainActivity.

Step 5: Further add this code

```
MediaPlayer ring= MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.ring);
ring.start();
```

Comment: Where should I add this code (in which XML-file) if I want the audio to start playing at the start of the APK?. Thnks

Comment: I really doubt you can straight away add an APK as an android studio project. The code is generally obfuscated and is present as `smali` files after decompiling.